# Check if values are not exists with WHERE IN clause - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey im writting sql query, I almost done it but I need to change important thing but still dont have idea to repair it. There is my SQL example

```sql
SELECT post.id,post.name as post_name,
(SELECT users.login FROM users WHERE post.creator = users.id) creator,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recommends WHERE recommends.idea_id = post.id) recommends,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.idea_id = post.id) comments,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ',') as tags
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN tags
ON post.id = tags.idea_id
WHERE post.name IN
(
    SELECT post.name FROM posts
    JOIN tags   ON post.id = post.idea_id
    WHERE tags.tag IN ('X','Y','Z')
)
GROUP BY post.name
```

What's the problem? If our X or Y or Z is not exist the query still working. I dont know how to repair, i tryed some NOT EXISTS clauses or NOT IT but it not working. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Your query makes perfect sense, looking for posts that have one of the tags -- although the query is over-complicated.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Yes but if one of the this tags from ('X','Y','Z') for example is not exists from posts tags, then result is false despite that rest are exists.

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking for posts that have *any* one of the tags, you can do:

```
SELECT post.id, post.name as post_name,
       (SELECT users.login FROM users WHERE post.creator = users.id) as creator,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recommends WHERE recommends.idea_id = post.id) as recommends,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.idea_id = post.id) as comments,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ',') as tags
FROM posts LEFT JOIN
     tags
     ON post.id = tags.idea_id
GROUP BY post.id, post.name
HAVING SUM(tags.tag IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')) > 0;
```

Note:  I changed the `GROUP BY` to include `post.id` (assuming that the name is unique for each `id`).  It is a good practice to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.  If the same name has multiple ids, then remove `post.id` from the `SELECT`.

If you want all three of the tags *and* there are no duplicates (a reasonable assumption), then change the `HAVING` to:

```
HAVING SUM(tags.tag IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')) = 3;
```